# iis7 urlrewriting without slash (pr remove check file exists)

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-7

I have a URL such as http://localhost/site/someName/file.ext, where file.ext are different variants and the files do not exist in the site folder.

in iis6 i create a module and uncheck "Check file exists", but in iis7 i can't find this option and I can't parse this request because IIS shows an error message:
`StaticFile 0x80070002`

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to Control Panel\Add Remove Programs\Change Windows Programs and drill into the IIS settings you should see Web Management Tools (or something similar) then you should find II6 Management Compatibility.  Make sure you have IIS 6 Management Console installed (it probably isn't).  You can then access the IIS6 console to add your mapping without the file having to exist (leave it to M$ to remove a simple flag like this in newer versions of their $oftware).

Also note that even once you get that configured there are changes in the way IIS 7 handles these requests that may cause you further grief.  I can't remember off the top of my head what specifically I ran into but it had to do with the web.config settings (and I'm pretty sure it through some sort of error that you can search for and get an answer pretty quickly).

This is my first answer so hope it helps and good luck!